# Why the type of "errno" in C is `int` rather than `unsigned int`?

Tags: c, errno

I'm new to C, just a question on global integer variable `errno`, the type of `errno` is `int` and its value range is 1 to 124, since the value can't be negative, then why its type is `int` rather than `unsigned int`?

Comment: Who says the value range is 1-106?

Comment: @Siguza 1 to 124 https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html

Comment: @secondimage The C standard only requires 3 errno codes to be defined. Implementations add their own, so there is no set range.

Comment: It likely stems from the fact that a long time ago in pre-standard C, everything defaulted to `int` unless otherwise specified. There are a number of value that are type `int` for that reason. You could ask the same about `main()`, since you are not to return negative values to the shell, why isn't it `unsigned main()`? Likely the very same reason.

Comment: http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html - not everyone uses the same errnos

Comment: I think the reason is simply historical - unsigned integers weren't part of the C language until 1973, probably after errno was created. There are other places in the APIs which in hindsight should be unsigned but aren't, some of which have been cleaned up over the years.

Comment: I found [this copy of the C90 standard](https://www.pdf-archive.com/2014/10/02/ansi-iso-9899-1990-1/ansi-iso-9899-1990-1.pdf), which in section 7.1.4, page 97, says that the value of `errno` can be nonzero integer. Then it was changed to be positive integer in C99, but keeping the `int` type. So maybe backwards compatibility?

Comment: I was going to add the [tag:history] tag, but it has says that computer history questions are off-topic. Does that mean that this question should be closed? If not, @EricS should post their comment as an answer.

Comment: As already said, probably for historical reasons. But since errno is not used with comparison operators like <, >, <= or >=, it is not really important and will probably not change.

Comment: @secondimage those are the error codes no RedHat 7.3 in 2004. That doesn't mean other platforms or later versions of RedHat has the same error values. For example https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/dima/for-travis/include/errno.h The POSIX standard only specifies [the following errnos](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) and [*The errno values in a 32-bit Windows operating system are a subset of the values for errno in XENIX systems*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-constants?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @AaronKeesing C90 7.1.4 says "the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions" and then later "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call". This is consistent with later standards and the same text exists in C17.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of things in C are `int` out of tradition, rather than because of some rationale. Back in the days when dinosaurs walked the earth, C didn't have much of a type system but treated everything as `int`. As the language developed and eventually got standardized, the type system got less crude but a lot of old functions retained `int` types for their API. (For example there's another such old `int` constant `EOF`, which in turn has affected the API of a lot of functions like `getchar` and the `ctype.h` functions.)

As for where `errno` is defined and what type it got, see C17 7.5 (errno.h)

> `errno`
> which expands to a modifiable lvalue that has type `int` and thread local storage
> duration

The only guarantee about its value is this:

> The value of `errno` in the initial thread is zero at program startup /--/
> but is never set to zero by any library function. The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call...

Note that it says *nonzero*, not *positive*. There are some pre-defined macros like `EDOM`, `EILSEQ`, `ERANGE` that are guaranteed to be positive `int`, but `errno` isn't restricted to just these values. The implementation (compiler & system) may define more values, as seen in Linux etc. The range 1 to 124 you speak of is specific to Linux, but nothing in C prevents other implementations from using different ranges or negative numbers.